# Haskell: Pattern matching with named fields

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, monads, monad-transformers

I got `ReaderT` from `Control.Monad.Reader`:

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
```

and `Action` from `Database.MongoDB.Query`:

```
type Action = ReaderT MongoContext
```

Query functions of MongoDB are something like this:

```
delete :: MonadIO m => Selection -> Action m ()
```

I'm trying to use pattern mathing with `Action m ()` to check if it is `Action IO ()` or `Action _ ()`

A simple case like this

```
case x of
  Action IO () -> True
  Action _ () -> False
```

doesn't work, because `Action` is not a data constructor. Probably I should use something like this:

```
case x of
  ReaderT MongoContext IO () -> True
  ReaderT MongoContext _ () -> False
```

But then I get an error:

```
The constructor ‘ReaderT’ should have 1 argument, but has been given 3
   In the pattern: ReaderT MongoContext IO ()
   In a case alternative:
      ReaderT MongoContext IO ()
```

Should I pass `MongoContext -> IO ()` instead? I'm out of ideas, please help me with that expression. Thanks <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IO is a type, you **absolutely cannot** case match against it, it only exists at compile time.

In general, if you have a type variable constrained by a type class, you can only call things supported by that type class. You cannot know which particular type it is unless the typeclass implements methods for inspecting it, like `Typeable`. Neither `Monad` nor `MonadIO` implement this kind of run-time type discrimination, so what you want is, by design, not possible.

Also note that, you don't need to know "which m" `delete` is, since it's specialized to whatever `m` that YOU want it to be, so long as it is an instance of `MonadIO`. You can simply declare `deleteIO sel = delete sel :: Action IO ()`

What are you actually trying to get done here?

Comment: Thanks a lot for response! I need a function

```f :: MonadIO m => Action m () -> m ()```

that has different behavior for ```Action IO ()``` and ```Action m ()```

Comment: @user8078566 You could use a typeclass and overlapping instances, but I'd rather avoid those. Why do you need a function with such a weird behavior? This looks as a consequence of a wrong decision elsewhere.

Comment: The entire purpose of `MonadIO` is that it is a class of Monads that lets you embed *the same* IO action into each of them. Furthermore, `Action m () -> m ()` is in effect 'running' the `Action`, not the monad, it really REALLY shouldn't behave differently depending on `m`. It sounds like what you probably want is your own type class. Where are you using this function?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Steven! My function basically runs a database query (which has type `MonadIO m => Action m ()`) and returns `m()`. I want this function to be applicable for IO and my own monad which implements `MonadIO` `MonadTrans` (StateT transformer) typeclass.

Comment: So i want to check: should i make a new connection (for `IO`) or get any existing connection from a state monad. I've decided to make two function. A typeclass like MongoRunner is probably a good idea also.

Comment: Your function will be applicable for both monad types if you use generic methods that don't fix the monad involved, it will simply work in both as each operation you perform will know how to specialise to any `MonadIO m` that it is called in. And you will probably be best served by retrieving any existing connection, and allowing the monad you are operating in to provide it however it chooses. Then your generic code doesn't have to think about how the connection is obtained, it simply has one.

Answer (score 0):

As [Steven Armstrong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1946543/steven-armstrong) said, what you're trying to do is very weird, you cannot pattern match on IO because is *an abstract data type* (constructors aren't visible) and if I were you I would rethink what I'm trying to achieve. Having said that, Haskell still gives you a way of inspecting types at runtime using [Typeable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) eg (inside a ghci session):

```
import Data.Typeable
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

type MyType = ReaderT String IO

f :: MyType ()
f = ReaderT $ \env -> putStrLn env

checkF :: Typeable a => MyType a -> Bool
checkF x = case show (typeOf x) of
  "ReaderT * [Char] IO ()" -> True
  _                        -> False

-- checkF f => True
```